# How to get output from trigger on linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger, linked-server

Fair warning, I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I'm trying to extend some existing code without needing to do a rewrite.

Anyway, I've got two SQL Server 2012 installs, one local in my office and another at a remote site.  The server at the remote site has a linked server setup for my local system.

An application at the remote site inserts a record to a table on the linked server which has an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.  That trigger has a select statement at the end which returns a single integer value.  If I do the insert on the local box in SSMS I get the integer as output.  If I do the insert on the remote box all I get is `1 row(s) affected`.

Is there anyway I can get the trigger's output passed back to the linked server or am I going to need to rewrite as a stored procedure?

*TEXT BELOW HERE IS BASED ON CLARIFICATION REQUESTED IN COMMENTS*

All connections are made in the security context of a single user on the remote side. The output appears as expected if I use `EXECUTE AS USER` on the local server to do the insert rather than do it across the link, so it isn't a permission issue with the account.

Server options are:

```
Collation Compatible=False  
Data Access=True  
RPC=True  
RPC Out=True  
Use Remote Collation=True  
Collation Name=(blank)  
Connection Timeout=0  
Query Timeout=0  
Distributor=False  
Publisher=False  
Subscriber=False  
Lazy Schema Validation=False  
Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction=True
```

Comment: What are the linked server settings that you have currently ?

Comment: @Kin All connections are made in the security context of a single user on the remote side.  Server options are: Collation Compatible=False, Data Access=True, RPC=True, RPC Out=True, Use Remote Collation=True, Collation Name=(blank), Connection Timeout=0, Query Timeout=0, Distributer=False, Publisher=False, Subscriber=False, Lazy Schema Validation=False, Enable Promotion of Distributed Transaction=True

Comment: Can you try using `sp_executesql` with OUTPUT clause ?

Comment: I ended up just rewriting the code as a stored procedure. The more I reviewed the trigger code the less happy I was about just modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about modifying your trigger to put that integer into a table?  Include some identifying information, say the primary key from the table you are inserting into.  Then just query the table after the insert.

Comment: The system doing the insert doesn't have an identifier, this process is what generates one.  If a bunch of inserts happened at once there would be no way for the client to know which record in the outputmtable was theirs.  I'll try that on Monday though so I can figure out if that works.

Comment: Putting logging in the trigger is the way to go here, but the danger is setting up a big distributed transaction where the insert fires, plus the output table is read, all from a transaction done across servers. Recipe for concurrency problems there.